# Bitcoin Exchange Volume Ticker API Error [PHP]

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

I am trying to get the volumes from a couple exchanges. When I load this  nothing loads except a blank page. Maybe a small error I missed?

```
<?php

function getData($url) {
$decode = file_get_contents($url);
return json_decode($decode, true);
}

//BTC Volume on BTCE
$BTCVolumeBTCE = getData('https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd');
$BTCEVolume = $BTCVolumeBTCE["btc_usd"]["vol_cur"];

//BTC Volume on Bitstamp
$BTCVolumeStamp = getData('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
$StampVolume = $BTCVolumeStamp["volume"];

//BTC Volume on OKCoin
$BTCVolumeOK = getData('https://www.okcoin.com/api/ticker.do?ok=1')
$OKCoinVolume = $BTCVolumeOK["vol"];

//BTC Volume Bitfinex
$BTCVolumeFinex = getData('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd');
$FinexVolume = $BTCVolumeFinex["volume"]

//BTC Volume LakeBTC
$BTCVolumeLake = getData('https://www.lakebtc.com/api_v1/ticker');
$LakeVolume = $BTCVolumeLake["USD"]["volume"]

?>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error logs. There could be a timeout or other error.

Where the log is located depends on your OS and/or server. If you are using an Apache on a Ubuntu environment you'll find the logs most likely under `/var/log/apache/error.log`. Do `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log` in the console, refresh the page and look if there is something written.

Comment: Ok I'll try to find them.

Comment: Which OS and server are you using?

Comment: Yes, like @Darkstar said. You missed the semicolon on line 17. Now where you know where to find the error log you can easily get information about your errors. What would help as well is an IDE.